# Can I use websocket for my Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that will complete its task in around 50 secs. I tried to invoke the function using API Gateway, but API Gateway timeout is around 30 seconds!

So, I am looking for workaround.

I found that I can use WebSocket to invoke a Lambda function.

My Question is:

If Websocket connects to the Lambda function and the function completes its task in 50 secs and returns a response, will the Lambda function be running ever??

Or Suppose 5 Users invoke the Lambda function using Websocket Function. Can they all be using the same Lambda? Or Different Lambda?

If they are using the same Lambdas, then after  15 minutes lambda will time out.

I am confused. Can I use websocket for my Lambda function or use another way like SNS,SQS etc?